# Clarification on well formed, logically provable, provable and true formulas

Tags: first-order-logic

Given a first order logic with equality,
I provide some names:

$\mathscr{L}$ be the language with a fixed signature.

$\Sigma_*$ the set of all well-formed formulas of the language.

$\Sigma_{L+E}$ the set of all the logical and equality axioms as formulas.

$\Sigma_{T}$ a (variable) set consisting of non logical axioms as formulas.

$\Sigma_{(L+E)^d}$ the set of formulas than can be derived as theorems within the deductive system from $\Sigma_{L+E}$ as axioms. Are these exacty the logically valid formulas?

$\Sigma_{(T)^d}$ the set of formulas than can be derived as theorems within the deductive system from $\Sigma_{L+E}$ and $\Sigma_{T}$  as axioms.

$\mathscr{A}$ a fixed structure that interprets the language.

$\Sigma_{\mathscr{A}}$ the set of formulas that are true under this structure.

No matter which $\Sigma_{T}$ as subset of $\Sigma_*$ I choose, is it true that:

$\Sigma_{L+E}$ $\subset$ $\Sigma_{(L+E)^d}$ $\subset$ $\Sigma_{(T)^d}$ $\subset$ $\Sigma_*$ ?

$\Sigma_{T}$ $\subset$ $\Sigma_{(T)^d}$ $\subset$ $\Sigma_*$ ?

$\Sigma_{L+E}$ $\subset$ $\Sigma_{(L+E)^d}$ $\subset$ $\Sigma_{\mathscr{A}}$ $\subset$ $\Sigma_*$ ?

Now assuming $\mathscr{A}$ is a model of $\Sigma_{T}$, so as bonus point $\Sigma_{T}$ is consistent, is it true that:

$\Sigma_{T}$ $\subset$ $\Sigma_{(T)^d}$ $\subset$ $\Sigma_{\mathscr{A}}$ $\subset$ $\Sigma_*$ ?

Is $\Sigma_{T}$ what is usually called a first order theory?

For $\Sigma_{T}$ to be complete means that for any $\phi\in\Sigma_*$ then $\phi\in\Sigma_{(T)^d}$ or $\neg\phi\in\Sigma_{(T)^d}$ ?

For $\Sigma_{T}$ to be consistent means that for any $\phi\in\Sigma_{T}$ then $\neg\phi\not\in\Sigma_{(T)^d}$ ?

Comment: And if someone could provide a better naming for this sets, or maybe the usual name this sets have in logic texts it would be very useful...

Comment: The answer to every single one of your questions is **yes**. A key point is that the deductive closure operation $\mathsf{Ded}$ (your "$\Sigma_T\mapsto\Sigma_{(T)^d}$") is monotonic: if $A\subseteq B$ then $\mathsf{Ded}(A)\subseteq\mathsf{Ded}(B)$. This is a good exercise and trivially solves multiple of your questions.